# How do fix this pop up drain stopper in the sink

Tags: sink, sinkhole

The thing goes from and cannot move up

[image]

Comment: So the pop-up drain stopper no longer moves?  You might want to [edit your question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/161674/edit) with a more complete sentence/description.

Comment: A photo of the underside of the sink with a clear view of the rod and pop-up mechanism (usually at the rear of the basin) might help as well.